# How to validate a record before insert in the table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables. In table2 I have foreign key from table1.

When I am inserting a record in table2 and the foreign key (IDFK) has a value 1 then i need to have value for Country, if IDFK has a value 2 then i need to have value Date and DueDate. Columns Country, Date and DueDate are nullable. But they must have some values depending on the value of IDFK.

Is it possible to preserve this rule without the logic at insert statement.

**Table1**:

```
Id  Name
==============
1   Europe
2   Australia
```

**Table2**:

```
Id  IDFK    Name        Country   Date          DueDate
===========================================================
1   1       Package1    France    NULL          NULL
2   1       Package2    Spain     NULL          NULL
3   2       Package3    NULL      2016-02-21    2016-03-24 
4   2       Package4    NULL      2016-02-24    2016-03-24
```

Comment: i think you can write a trigger on insert for this check.

Comment: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175089(v=sql.105).aspx use INSTEAD OF INSERT, it will do the trick for you.

Comment: I'd suggest to build this validation on app side or develop a stored proc for appending data. This is not an auditing or low-level control (valid email or smth) - this is a high-level "business" knowledge.